# The difference between 'gonna have to' and 'will have to'

Tags: grammar, differences, will-be-going

Can anyone explain the difference between 'will have to' and 'gonna have to', please? I'm not native speaker and these statements seem exactly the same to me.

Comment: _Gonna_ is a dialectical form of _going to_. If you look for the difference between _going to_ and _will_, you'll find there is a perceived difference in certainty about the described action. For more details, you might want to have a look at [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Yeah, "gonna" is colloquial for "going to" (and since it's colloquial it should not be used in formal writing, etc).  The "correct" form of "gonna have to", though, would be "going to have to", which is a bit awkward to say, even for a native English speaker, whereas "will have to" conveys (nearly) the same meaning with a much "smoother" flow of words.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to have to renew your passport. (future intention - sounds horrible without "gonna") means you'll have to do it in the near future. ("gonna" is a colloquialism for "going to")

You have to renew your passport. (present simple) It refers to the present.

You will have to renew your passport. (future simple) You'll have to do it at some unspecified time in the future.